# MERGE using Rowid Oracle Conversion in Postgres

Tags: oracle, postgresql

Can some help me the best way convert the below Oracle code to Postgres

```
MERGE INTO INCLUSION_EXCLUSION_ALL A
USING (SELECT DISTINCT IEALL.rowid rid, IE.BLACKOUT_DURATION, ie.BLACKOUT_CATEGORY
        FROM INCLUSION_EXCLUSION_ALL IEALL, INCLUSION_EXCLUSION_RULES IE
       WHERE IE.PRI_PROMOTION_ID = IEALL.PRI_PROMOTION_ID 
         AND IE.PRI_OFFER_ID = IEALL.PRI_OFFER_ID
         AND IE.SEC_PROMOTION_ID = IEALL.SEC_PROMOTION_ID 
         AND IE.SEC_OFFER_ID = IEALL.SEC_OFFER_ID
         AND IE.BLACKOUT_DURATION > 0
         AND (IEALL.BLACKOUT_DURATION <> IE.BLACKOUT_DURATION OR IEALL.BLACKOUT_CATEGORY <> IE.BLACKOUT_CATEGORY)
         --AND IE.INCL_EXCL_IND <> 'I'
         AND IE.SECONDARY_TYPE = 'B') B
     ON (A.rowid = B.rid)
   WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET A.BLACKOUT_DURATION = B.BLACKOUT_DURATION, A.BLACKOUT_CATEGORY = B.BLACKOUT_CATEGORY;
```

Thank You,
I want to know different ways on how we can do it as the rowid's are involved in here and are not compatible with Postgres esp in Joining using Alias even by using CTID,

Please advise

Comment: @APC - `rowid` used this way is a very reasonable (and common) hack, used to work around an unreasonable Oracle restriction on the `merge` statement. Namely, Oracle does not allow you to update a column used in the `on` clause.

Comment: @user10531062 - do you know why the Oracle query was written that way? Was it - as @Mathguy proposes - because the join you'd like to use for the ON clause would have included one or more of the updated columns? Basically, if you're saying you can't substitute `ctid` for `rowid` in the ON clause it seems the only solution is to re-write the MERGE statement so it works. But that requires an understanding of your data model, your data and your business logic that we do not have.

Comment: @APC - the easiest way to see that the restriction is unreasonable is to note that the same restriction does NOT exist when you update through a join (as long as the necessary condition is met: a unique constraint or index on the join column in the SOURCE table). Oracle has no problem with it in an `update`, but it does in `merge`. Probably due to their implementation of the operation, not for good logical reasons. I don't think there is such a restriction on `merge` in the SQL Standard.

Comment: @APC - Completely understandable, but If you see the code, rowid is an inbuilt Oracle psudo column but unfortuantely looks like there is nothing like that in Postgresql, reason why CTID doesn't fit in our code, rather I wrote one single update statement but looks like its not performance friendly as its taking forever to execute the statement by using primary key in Join in Postgres rather than Rowid, created the indexes to those tables similar to oracle, but performance is a concern in Postgres unlike Oracle,
Please correct me if I miss something,